# Angular - Add property bindings and events to transcluded element in component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular component that contains an `<input/>` element which the component adds property bindings and an event listener to. I'm looking into allowing the consuming component to specify a custom input field (potentially with parent(s)) via transclusion. The current WIP in the component;

```
<!-- Container for the transcluded element -->
<div #inputWrapper>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<!-- Default element to display if no element provided -->
<ng-container *ngIf="inputWrapper.children.length == 0">
  <input 
    [value]="getValue()" 
    [ngClass]="options.inputClasses" 
    (click)="onClick()"
    [attr.placeholder]="options.placeholder"
    type="text"
  >
</ng-container>
```

The intention is that if the component is used like;

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

Then the default input will be used, but if a custom input is provided;

```
<my-component>
  <input type="text">
</my-component>
```

Then the provided input will be used instead. With the example above this functions (i.e. the custom input is displayed instead). The additional complexity with this is that potentially the custom input field could have parent elements, for example when using Angular Material;

```
<my-component>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="My Custom Input">
  </md-input-container>
</my-component>
```

What is the best way to get a handle on a transcluded input field and add bindings to it (mainly the `[value]` and `(click)` bindings from the default input so they behave like the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

I think the easiest way is to pass a `<template>` (or `<ng-template>` in Angular4) like

```
<my-component>
  <template let-item><input [value]="option.value" type="text"></template>
</my-component>
```

this way you don't need the `<ng-content>`

In `MyComponent`

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template:TemplateRef;
```

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: options}"></template>
```

I'm not sure how the value passed to `[ngOutletContext]="..."` should exactly look like for your use case, because I don't think I fully understand your requirements.